# arduino(microusb) and windows phone 8/8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to have serial communication through usb port  with arduino in  windows phone 8/8.1 ,i would like to know if it is possible ..

Have seen sample which works with Bluetooth  [Link](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_communicating_with_Arduino_using_Bluetooth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you would need a USB serial driver and that's not something you're likely to find on a consumer phone. You may have some luck using a [Microsoft Windows Embedded 8.1 Handheld for Mobile Rugged Industrial, Commercial, Automotive, and POS Mobile Enterprise Applications](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/windows-embedded-8-handheld.aspx).[1] But you'll want to verify support with the manufacturer.

[1] Named by committee